# sed variable substitution using string

Tags: linux, git, sed, git-filter-branch

How to pass argument to sed without input files. The sed is in single quote and has pipe in it already.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter \
      'git ls-files -s | sed -i "s-\t\"*-&dirname/-" |
                GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                git update-index --index-info &&
       mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

The above code works fine if dirname is hard-coded. But i need to pass the dirname from command line arguments to script. I am trying like below but no luck.

```
 'set subdir=$folder;git ls-files -s | sed -i "s-\t\"*-&$subdir/-" |
```

The sed says input file is missing. I can not directly pass the input file to sed. I am seeing error like below.

```
Rewrite 9c86de42b7f3228e3d45a278c8caf7e24c8e55cf (1/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
sed: no input files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices here.  You can either evaluate `$subdir` to build up a fixed `sed` command that you then set as your filter; or you can evaluate a variable in the shell fragment that `git filter-branch` will invoke.

To understand the latter, realize that your `--index-filter` string becomes [an ordinary shell variable](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/git-filter-branch.sh#L169-L171):

```
--index-filter)
    filter_index="$OPTARG"
;;
```

which is then [passed to `eval`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/git-filter-branch.sh#L425-L426):

```
eval "$filter_index" < /dev/null ||
    die "index filter failed: $filter_index"
```

The `eval` means that the expression in `$filter_index`, set from your `--index-filter` argument, has access to all the shell variables and functions in [the filter-branch script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh).  Unfortunately, none of its *private* variables holds the expression you'd like—but you can access its *environment* variables, which means you can put the value into an environment variable.  In other words, you could supply `subdir=<whatever>` as an *environment* to your original expression.

In any case, as [bk2204 answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351109/1256452), you need to remove the `-i` option.  Besides that, some versions of `sed` don't accept `\t` as a tab character (presumably yours does, just be aware of this).

To expand the variable earlier, just do that.  For instance:

```
... --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&'$folder'/-" | ...
```

(I've removed the `-i` here myself).  Note how this exits single quotes, expands `$folder`, then re-enters single quotes.  If `$folder` might contain whitespace, be sure to use double quotes while expanding it here:

```
... --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&'"$folder"'/-" | ...
```

The nesting of quotes here is pretty tricky: the stuff inside the single quotes is all one big string, provided as the argument that sets the variable `$filter_index` inside the `filter-branch` script.  The `eval` runs it through a second pass of evaluation, breaking up into the pipeline (`git ls-files`, piped to `sed`, piped to `git update-index`) and running the various multiple commands, all of which have their stdin redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I tried the latter and it worked. Its a complete answer and it saved a lot of time. The eval seems to be solve passing arguments when nested. I will give a try while updating the script further.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `sed -i`, which edits its command-line arguments (which are names of files) in place. However, you're reading from standard input and haven't provided any command-line arguments. If you want to just filter the standard input like this, omit the `-i` from your `sed` command.

Comment: I have assigned the cmd-line args to variable folder and used like below. But seeing error.

     'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&$folder/-" |

Rewrite d97350e369514528ea545e200cf1481cdae3ac61 (1/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    Ignoring path /index.js
mv: cannot stat '/home/apurb/git_poc/poc-apollo-server/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
index filter failed: git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&$folder/-" |
  GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
   git update-index --index-info &&
  mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"

Comment: The value from $folder is not passed properly and hence the git command is failing.If $folder value is hard-coded in the sed then the git command is working.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Removing  option "-i" in sed ignores in the input. In addition, the single qoute and double quote the $folder does the trick as pointed by torek.